# How to create binary TIFF image?

Tags: conversion, tiff

Is there any utility to create/convert a image to binary TIFF image. I want to use that binary tiff image as a input to a software ( an open source project which takes only binary tiff images as  input).

Comment: potential duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/77596/how-can-multiple-image-tiff-files-be-converted-to-jpeg-files -- asks about the opposite direction (TIFF -> something else), but the utilities there should also do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ImageMagick's convert option with the -monochrome parameter, for example:

```
convert -monochrome input.tif output.tif
```

Convert has many options for compression, threshold, filtering, etc. See [this link](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) for the options. ImageMagick runs on Linux and Windows.